# My Python list is getting cleared though I'm not clearing it

Tags: python, list, selenium

I'm trying to append a temporary list (temp) to the main list (dfl) where the temporary list changes the elements inside it each iteration of a for loop.

The code snippet is below-

```
for i in range(1,n+1):#n is the number of rows
    for j in range(2,8):
        data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath").text #Data is derived from a website element by element
        temp.append(data)
    dfl.append(temp)
    print(dfl)
    temp.clear()
```

Now, the `print(dfl)`gets me the desired output, `[[list1],[list2]]`.
But when  I execute the same `print(dfl)` outside the  for loop, its printing out two empty lists like so `[[],[]]`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: the dfl you are asking outside the for loop can you describe which for loop as you have two for loops   can you show what are you trying means the code

Comment: Outside the first/main for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dfl.append(temp)` doesn't append the values of `temp`, it append a reference to `temp`. You need to append a copy of `temp`

```
for i in range(1,n+1):#n is the number of rows
    for j in range(2,8):
        data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath").text #Data is derived from a website element by element
        temp.append(data)
    dfl.append(temp[:])
    print(dfl)
    temp.clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

because you clear it with temp.clear()

the temp in dfl is the same object as the temp.

you can try:

```
import copy
...
dfl.append(copy.deepcopy(temp))
```